# Select2 on Clone Element not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I have select with multiple select like this

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple" multiple="multiple"  style="width:100%">
    <option value="月曜日">月曜日</option>
    <option value="火曜日">火曜日</option>
</select>
```

And I initialize it like this

```
$(".js-example-basic-multiple").select2();
```

It's working perfectly , but the problem when I want to clone it and append to other.

```
var clone_temp = $(".js-example-basic-multiple").clone();
  $("#some_wrapper").append( clone_temp  );
```

It's only work for first element ,but for clone element not working.
Please help!!!

Comment: run `clone_temp.select2();` after appending.

Comment: I tried , but not work

Answer (score 4):

Running `clone_temp.select2();` after appending will initialize the plugin again.

Working [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/8h7q1mbq/)

Code which i used:

```
$('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();
var clone_temp = $(".js-example-basic-multiple").clone();
$("#some_wrapper").append(clone_temp);
clone_temp.select2()
```

Comment: when I call clone_temp.select2() inside my function it show Uncaught query function not defined for Select2 s2id_autogen1

Comment: there is no way that would happen. you are not getting any error for `$('.js-example-basic-multiple').select2();`?

Comment: It work for the first time when page loaded , but when I clone the select2() function stop working. @Cerlin Boss

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a deep clone to clone the data and events as well : https://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents

```
var clone_temp = $(".js-example-basic-multiple").clone(true, true);
$("#some_wrapper").append( clone_temp  );
```

Comment: this doesnt work since `select2` will hide the actual select box and built a fake select using jquery and css. so you have to reinit the select2 again after appending.

Comment: when I click on clone element it work on first element @DarkMukke

Comment: @CerlinBoss, ah, fair enough. i understood the question in the way i answered it